# JQuery undefined object attribute still causes error even when not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating through an api object and certain results do not have a specific attribute. I used this to make a placeholder if the attribute was missing:

```
if (data.track[i].image == undefined) {
    urlstring = "path/to/image";
} else {
  urlstring = data.track[i].image[4][0];
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, even though the else clause shouldn't trigger if the attribute is undefined.

Comment: Obviously `data.track` itself is `undefined`, that is not what you are checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `data.track[i].image[4]` is `undefined` while your code seems to expect an array.

You might use

```
if (data.track[i].image && data.track[i].image[4]) {
    urlstring = data.track[i].image[4][0];
} else {
    urlstring = "path/to/image";
}
```

Note: I assumed the mix between `data.track[i]` and `data.toptracks.track[i]` is an artefact of the question.

Comment: it still gives the same error unfortunately. But this time, the error is on the "if" line